# Spring Async - Can't get async bean

Tags: java, spring, proxy, classcastexception, spring-3

```
ApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(Config.class);

AsyncBean session = ctx.getBean(AsyncBean.class);

Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: $Proxy14 cannot be cast to AsyncBean
```

Can't figure out how to use @Async with @EnableAsync....it seems to produce proxies and I can't get a handle to the singleton.

Another example:

```
@Bean
public Bean bean(){
   Bean bean=new Bean();
   bean.registerHandler(asyncBean());
}

@Bean 
public AsyncBean asyncBean(){
   return new AsyncBean();
 }
```

This also throws the same class cast exception... Caused by:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: $Proxy14 cannot be cast to AsyncBean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring requires AsyncBean to be an interface not a class. In general the proxied class must be an interface.

Answer (score 0):

Does AsyncBean implement an interface. If so by default Spring generates interface based JDK proxies.In order to lookup the bean from the context you have to use one of the interfaces implemented by the bean.For example

```
public class AsyncBean implements CertainInterface{
}
```

You can access it as CertainInterface c = ctx.getBean(CertainInterface.class);

If AsyncBean does not implement any interface then Spring uses CGLIB class based proxies. If thats the case then your code will work.

If you want AsyncBean to still implement an interface but your want to use class based proxies then you can instruct Spring to do so use @EnableAsync(proxyTargetClass=true)